# Errors running spark job locally in Zeppelin notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I've installed spark on my Mac and everything works fine when I run a spark-submit job in terminal or when I use spark-shell. I also installed Zeppelin, but when I try running a simple `sc` in a Zeppelin notebook I get the following error.

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compileSourcesKeepingRun(IMain.scala:432)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compileAndSaveRun(IMain.scala:855)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compile(IMain.scala:813)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:675)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:712)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietBind$1.apply(IMain.scala:711)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietBind$1.apply(IMain.scala:711)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietBind(IMain.scala:711)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$loopPostInit(ILoop.scala:891)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.callMethod(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:270)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.callMethod(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:262)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala211Interpreter.open(SparkScala211Interpreter.scala:84)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.NewSparkInterpreter.open(NewSparkInterpreter.java:102)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Versions:
- Zeppelin: 0.8.0
- Scala: 2.12.8
- Spark: 2.3.2
- Java: 11.0.2

3 things I included in zeppelin-env.sh:
- export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python
- export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.2/libexec
- export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/bin/hadoop

Does anyone know what might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if your spark home path is correct. Also try setting spark interpreter to local on Zeppelin web console

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JAVA_HOME is set.